# Как вывести колонку ManyToManyField в admin и на сайте?

Tags: python, django

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Bd, Category


class AdminBd(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'content')
    filter_horizontal = ['category', ]


admin.site.register(Bd, AdminBd)
admin.site.register(Category)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Категория')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_ulr(self):
        return reverse('category', kwargs={"category_id": self.pk})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'
        ordering = ['title', ]


class Bd(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Имя')
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1500, verbose_name='Именование')
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Category', verbose_name='Категория')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photo/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Картинка')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата публикации')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Обновлено')
    is_created = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Создан мной')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_ulr(self):
        return reverse('view_news', kwargs={"news_id": self.pk})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Объявление'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Объявления'
        ordering = ['-updated_at', '-created_at']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Bd


def index(request):
    bd = Bd.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'news_test/index.html', {'bd': bd})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не давно делал такую задачу. Значит в модель нужно добавить метод:

def get_category(self):
return ",".join([str(p) for p in self.сategory.all()])

И в admin.p yказать его в list_display

list_display = ('name', 'content', 'get_category')

Comment: Очень долго искал (дня 2) , но не нашел (точнее похоже нашел, но не понял этого). Вообщем, большое спасибо!